# Is it possible to generate different QR code from same input string on Android using Zxing?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, qr-code, zxing

I want my app to generate different QR code for the same input string. This QR code should be changing every certain time. Is it possible to achieve this using ZXing library on android?

```
onClick method{
try {
                    encriptionString=editText.getText().toString();
                    Bitmap bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(encriptionString);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (WriterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

}


Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String str) throws WriterException {
        BitMatrix result;
        try {
            result = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(str,
                    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 250, 250, null);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            // Unsupported format
            return null;
        }
        int w = result.getWidth();
        int h = result.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            int offset = y * w;
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
            }
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 250, 0, 0, w, h);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Actually I introduce a simple string and I get my QR code. But I want to know if it's possible to get a different QR code for same String.

Comment: There are different kinds of encoding schemes you can use, but a QR code literally is just a string, so for a given scheme same input in should give the same output. You could perhaps try appending redundant kinds of whitespace to the string to introduce some variation, then trim the result after decoding?

Comment: Thanks for that useful info @Mapsy